# make all connections to ip go to another one at system level on linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip

If I have an IP address `x.x.x.x` is there a way to map it at system level to another IP `y.y.y.y`?. In similar fashion to hostname mapping using /etc/host.

Both x.x.x.x and y.y.y.y refer to the same machine, but a software outside my control is sending the `x.x.x.x` IP instead of the `y.y.y.y` and passing it to another software outside my control. The `x.x.x.x` IP is not accessible from the server that I am using.

Comment: The title says "connections from ip" but after reading the body I think it's about "connections *to*". Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iptables` is capable of rewriting the destination IP address:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -j DNAT -d x.x.x.x --to-destination y.y.y.y
```